# Set the base URI when loading triples using Jena tdbloader

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki, apache-jena, turtle-rdf

I would like to set the base url when I load data into Fuseki using `tdbloader` or `tdbloader2`. Currently the local path is used as base, which is not what I want. Example:

```
# mytriple.ttl

@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
<#myitem> a owl:Thing .
```

`./tdbloader --loc /path/to/database /path/to/local/file/mytriple.ttl`

```
# sparql query example

PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>    
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object .
  ?subject a owl:Thing .
}
```

Query result:

`<file:///path/to/local/file/mytriple.ttl#myitem> rdf:type owl:Thing`

This is (1) not very clean to have in the database and (2) it leads to maintainability issues when I want to query a specific item when the base needs to be specified:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  ?subject a owl:Thing .
  <file:///path/to/local/file/mytriple.ttl#myitem> ?predicate ?object .
}
```

or

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
BASE <file:///path/to/local/file/mytriple.ttl>
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object
WHERE {
  ?subject a owl:Thing .
  <#myitem> ?predicate ?object .
}
```

How can I specify a different base in `tdbloader`, for example `<mydomain:myontology#>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in a `BASE` or `@base` statement into the data.  That way the data is stable - it will provide the same triples when used anywhere.

Or to avoid editing the file is:

```
cat "MyBase.ttl" "MyData.ttl" > D.ttl 
tdbloader --loc DB D.ttl
```